# Can an Angular app integrate with Braintree API to manage recurrent billing without traditional server side facilitation?

Tags: angular, aws-lambda, angular8, braintree, braintree-vault

I am fairly new to Braintree integration.

I am working on an Angular application that I would like to integrate with Braintree to manage user subscription.

If I understand it right, I think my Angular App cannot directly interact with Braintree api to manage user subscription. Is that correct?

It looks like I would need to have a backend (ex. Node.js express server) to facilitate the interaction.

I have also found that Braintree provides GraphQL api but I don’t see any documentation talking about subscription. Is it not supported at this time?

I have also thought about creating AWS lambda function to host the server side requirement for Braintree integration if a server end is a must. Would it suffice ?

Thank you in advanced

Update:

I was able to figure out how to tie everything up.
I used a lambda rest api with Amplify to interact with Braintree servers. Then my client app uses that REST api to conduct the billing process Braintree has lined out within their official document.

Answer (score 0):

A server is required for Braintree.

The graphQL API supports vaulting payment methods, so you can implement subscriptions that way. I didn't see support for automatic recurring billing / subscriptions, but it might be possible

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'll look closer into document for it. :)

Comment: I confirmed that the GraphQL API doesn't support recurring billing at present. So you can use vaulting and your own engine with it, or the classic API for recurring billing

Comment: Thank you for saving me the time. It looks like the traditional API is the only to go as of now. I know they are still working on serverless design. I wonder when it would be ready.